# How to pass parameter to java lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, spring-retry, retrytemplate

I am using Spring RetryTemplate and using this method.  Wanted to pass some argument (vendor) it is giving me compilation error. I can create a another variable vendorName as final can send it.  But I want to make use the the variable `vendor`. It must be simple one but not getting it.  please help.

```
public Token getToken(final String tokenId) {
    String vendor = getVendor(tokenId);//returns some vendor name
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = getRetryTemplate();
    Token token = retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
        logger.info("Attempted {} times", context.getRetryCount());
        return retrieveToken(tokenId, vendor);
    });
}

private RetryTemplate getRetryTemplate() {

    final FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(getRandomNumber() * 1000);

    final SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(5);

    final RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

    return retryTemplate;
}
```

compilation error is: Local variable vendor defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Comment: So, what's the exact and comple compilation error?

Comment: I updated with error. It is related java lambda passing parameter.

Comment: @Kiran `vendor` seems to be effectively final from what i can observe

Comment: That code can't produce that error.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to Java 8, we cannot use a non-final local variable in an anonymous class.
It's very useful in the context of the lambda expression as well. 
Please check below link 
[Java Lambda Expression with Non-final Function Paramter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940323/java-lambda-expression-with-non-final-function-paramter)

Better to modify your code

```
public Token getToken(final String tokenId) {
    final String vendor = getVendor(tokenId);//returns some vendor name
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = getRetryTemplate();
    Token token = retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
        logger.info("Attempted {} times", context.getRetryCount());
        return retrieveToken(tokenId, vendor);
    });
}
```

Or Assign vendor value in another final variable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use non-final variables in a lambda.

One option is to set `vendor` to final

Alternatively, you can refactor to just use a for loop instead.

Comment: I can not set because i have some logic based on that i am setting vendor.  I can create another variable as final to use.  But I want to pass existing instead of creating a new one.

Comment: @Kiran then you'll have to copy it to a variable that is final.  There is no way around this.

Comment: @LouisWasserman okay. I was thinking we can pass a variable. If that is the only option then i will do. thanks